# authentication with Cognito pool per tenant

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, multi-tenant

I am watching an AWS reInvent video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmVUbngCyOw&feature=emb_logo&ab_channel=AmazonWebServices  where it suggests to use Cognito pool per tenant.
This is what the authentication looks like and introduces an Auth manager to Auth against Cognito and gets back a JWT token based on OpenIdConnect.

[image]

I was reading another blog post here:  https://medium.com/@tarekbecker/serverless-enterprise-grade-multi-tenancy-using-aws-76ff5f4d0a23

and It suggested using a Custom Authorizer attached to the API gateway.

[image]
Am I right in understanding that we should basically be authenticating in 2 places ->

1. From the web app using Auth Service
2. At API gateway using custom authorizer

Comment: It depends to your purpose, I don't even do that both approaches. I am implementing several approaches for my authentication & authorization. Mostly  Cognito User Pool Host UI with federated identity. So back to your purpose?

Comment: @MahdiRidho : Use case is cognito pool per tenant so Auth service authenticates user in the given userpool for that user

Comment: then you just create an user pool for multiple app clients there. every app clients will have their own setting including unique ID, domain name, callback url, and providers. To be highlighted, user pool is just authentication layer. You should need a middle role to have access into AWS services. It means although the users has been authenticated, they will access the AWS Services with identity roles. If you use API Gateway, it will stand with lambda as trusted role generally. Other approach with aws sdk, you can set the user pool as federated identity to be authenticated role

Answer (score 0):

Generally, people use the AWS SDK to authenticate the user from Cognito and it handles the whole authentication logic. AWS-SDK is available in almost all popular languages.

As API gateway is the frontline service or the publically exposed service through which you can access the microservices hosted using Lambda. Also, ApiGateway interacts as an intermediary/broker service between any client application including Web and Lambda microservices.

Custom Authorizer is used for implementing the custom authorization logic at the API Gateway service i.e. if a user role doesn't have any access to certain Apis it'd just give an error to the user trying to access those resources.

For example how we used Custom Authorizer in the past. We had users with 2 role types

1. Admin
2. User
   We had to restrict the access of the admin Apis. So we added all this logic to authorize access to the Apis based on the information we get in the bearer token.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-custom-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway/

[image]

Comment: Use case is cognito pool per tenant so Auth service authenticates user in the given userpool for that user

Comment: It's your choice if you add any Auth service to authenticate. Every user pool has unique identity through which you can authenticate from the mobile or web SDK.